# Podio Api:use java lib create space success,but in my podio board page can't find the new wordspace

Tags: java, podio

when use java lib to create a space,it repsponse success,but in my podio board page can't find the new wordspace. and I use java lib to create app,it samely can't find in my podio board page.
it seems some thing not working.

by the way,my account is free.

[the java client print log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dnRB.png)

[not find the new space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J18VJ.png)

Comment: the java client log as flow:[Link](https://p5.zdusercontent.com/attachment/1544/eU6Pa39Cfk2Ua173BcjNYcTd3?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..OypMH3krH-xJc7tZnbtVcg.ZCKsef5btFhphIfb7y0cLdaQZhhQ7anJI0BbjpsvrVKsq2ZzLLth7bQ1tdGpgCV7UXn0uiFYoPmmVExlDWMVL43JlsF8MuyiY1-oEcxl11CDYaEeGz8lI4H50a8YB4yrAXt9qdfmj2AVcT8jXcL6-2qpzJX9pRZt3LyDKw8qeyQ00YoFZbsv-RlBNhy0U04h2rZAEL6Qj-iuEV-s0Bnar--BACWqmdhh-N8vybxsHHrPrLZHZ0UTzHYdxqNyvngKLyxUOpgmuy0sssMWVhiIXn_uyQ3GuyO1fjXRWd8QVXs.t3I3-4nNanXn-qkWkXWohA)

Comment: All of those images are the same. Have you tried `GET /space/org/{org_id}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,it have bean solved,
beacuse the java client lib test case is debug mode, 
after modify the param,it works. 
api = new ResourceFactory("api.podio.com", "files.podio.com", 443, true, false, CLIENT_CREDENTIALS, USER_CREDENTIALS_MAP.get(userId));